# Search and locate a column header using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a worksheet where the column header positions change regurlary.

For example if today "Date" is in column J1 as the column header, tomorrow "Date" could be in column C1. Therefore if I want to perform sorting operations, using a macro for date, I cannot refer to it using a hard-coded cell reference for example

```
cu.Range("J1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Date
```

Is there a way to search and locate a column header "Date". So that after I locate, I can perform the sorting based on current date?

Comment: Is this the same workbook ;) can you provide the `range("J1").Value` just to see your date format? So you're basically you want excel to auto-filter the column header of today?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Find` method to do this. Example:

```
Dim rngDateHeader As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range
Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row; adjust as needed.
Set rngDateHeader = rngHeaders.Find("Date")
```

You would then use `rngDateHeader` instead of the hard-coded `Range("J1")`.

Answer (score 2):

I love [Jean-Francois answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805144/5079799) and built a function off of it. Hope it helps!

Update based on feedback from @Chris.Neilson:

First off, when I started VBA I used the syntax `Range("Al:B1")` to define a range and that is why my function returned a string. Id use something like this:

```
Dim TestHeaderColStr As String
TestHeaderColStr = FindHeaderCol(1,"test")
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(TestHeaderColStr & "1:B1")
```

But, using numbers will save you headache and be much more readable like so:

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,2))
```

So it would be better to have the function return a LONG (Integer can be to small for the number of rows/columns in new Excel). It would be easy to transform the below function to return an Long by changing `As String` to `As Long` and then change the `Split` line to be `FindHeaderCol = rngHeaderCol.Column`

Note: If you do leave `As String` you can always convert to number via `Columns(FindHeaderCol(1,"test")).Column` (Eg: `debug.print Columns("G").Column`)

I changed my function to take the values VBA uses and defined the default I prefer and the enumerations of the terms you will see such as xlNext.

```
Public Const xlNext As Integer = 1
Public Const xlPrevious As Integer = 2
Public Const xlWhole As Integer = 1
Public Const xlPart As Integer = 2
Public Const xlByRows As Integer = 1
Public Const xlByColumns As Integer = 2
Public Const xlComments As Long = -4144
Public Const xlCommentsThreaded As Long = -4184
Public Const xlFormulas As Long = -4123
Public Const xlValues As Long = -4163
```

---

```
Public Function FindHeaderCol(ByVal rngHeaderRowInt As Long, ByVal HeaderColStr As String, Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet, Optional ByVal LookIn As Long = xlValues, Optional ByVal LookAt As Integer = xlPart, Optional ByVal SearchOrder As Integer = xlByRows, Optional ByVal SearchDirection As Integer = xlNext, Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal MatchByte As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal SearchFormat As Boolean = False) As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 If WS Is Nothing Then Set WS = ActiveSheet
 Dim rngHeaderRow As Range, rngHeaderCol As Range
 Set rngHeaderRow = WS.Rows(rngHeaderRowInt).Cells
 'expression.Find (What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
 Set rngHeaderCol = rngHeaderRow.Find(What:=HeaderColStr, After:=rngHeaderRow.Cells(rngHeaderRow.Count), LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, SearchOrder:=SearchOrder, SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
 If Not rngHeaderCol Is Nothing Then FindHeaderCol = Split(Cells(1, rngHeaderCol.Column).Address, "$")(1)
ErrorHandler:
End Function
```

Testing:

```
Public Sub Test_FindHeaderCol()
 Debug.Print "xlNext = " & FindHeaderCol(1, "TEST", Worksheets("Sheet1"), , , , xlNext)
 Debug.Print "xlPrevious = " & FindHeaderCol(1, "TEST", Worksheets("Sheet1"), , , , xlPrevious)
 Debug.Print "xlNext/xlWhole = " & FindHeaderCol(1, "TEST", Worksheets("Sheet1"), , xlWhole, , xlNext, True)
 Debug.Print "xlPrevious/xlWhole = " & FindHeaderCol(1, "TEST", Worksheets("Sheet1"), , xlWhole, , xlPrevious, True)
End Sub
```

**Function:**

```
Function FindHeaderCol(rngHeaderRow, rngHeaderCol) As String
 Set rngHeaderRow = Range(rngHeaderRow)
 Set rngHeaderCol = rngHeaderRow.Find(rngHeaderCol)
 FindHeaderCol = Split(Cells(1, rngHeaderCol.Column).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

**Testing:** (Note: Enter the word "Test" as a column header anywhere in row 1)

```
Sub Test()
 testcol = FindHeaderCol("1:1", "Test")
 MsgBox testcol
End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers are you interested in a critique of the function?  FWIW I see quite a few issues.

Comment: OK.  Bugs: 1) when using Find, doing a left to right search, without specifying `After`, it defaults to the Top Left cell of the search range.  If the row contains >1 matches, and TL cell contains the search term, then your code will find the _second_ one.  Fix it by adding `After:=rngHeaderRow.Cells(rngHeaderRow.Count)`. 2) your `Split` is using an implicit `ActiveSheet` reference. 3) your are using `LookAt:=xlPart`.  For headers, `xlWhole` would make more sence, or at least make it optional. {to be continued...)

Comment: Improvements: 1) You are returning the column Name (Letter).  IMHO it would be better to return the column _Number_. In my experience I (almost) always need the number, not the letter. On the odd occasion I need the Name, it's easy to extract (as you have in the function).  2) Using `Find` has the side effect of changing some of the Find settings from what the user last used.  When doing a search in a single row, it's usually better to use `XMatch` (if you have it) or `Match`.  `XMatch` has the ability to do Right-to-Left search too. (to be continued...)

Comment: 3) You should add error handling in case the function is passed invalid parameters. 4) You don't really need to pass both a row number and worksheet.  Could be a range, which can then be either a whole row, < a whole row.   (You'll just need to decide how flexable you want it to be) 5) Would be nice to add optional case sensitivity

Comment: @chrisneilsen I updated answer based on your feedback. I added options for LookAt/Search direction and set defaults, added `After` portion. There is no need to specify a worksheet for the `SPLIT` function as its simply splitting a range `A1` to become `A` the function returns a string, not a range object. Added basic Error handeling. I briefly looked at `XMatch` but its not backwards compatible enough, but `Match` would be. I'm unsure if `FIND` has case-sensitivity options? The Row vs Range/Worksheet is again part of my adding to functions over time issue without changing existing code..